# Как использовать Stream повторно?

Tags: java, java-stream

Сегодня сидел разбирался с нововведениями Java 8. Когда попробовал на практике, сразу столкнулся с ошибкой. Наверное, я чего-то не знаю. Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так.

Вот такой код:

```
private boolean test( String line )
{
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    Stream<String> wordsStream = Arrays.asList(words).stream();
    for( int i=0; i < controlWords.length; i++ )
    {
        if( !wordsStream.anyMatch( Predicate.isEqual(controlWords[i]) ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Если массив `controlWords` имеет размер > 1, то всё время получаю ошибку

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon
>   or closed

Если же метод чуть-чуть видоизменить, то проблема исчезнет:

```
private boolean test( String line )
{
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    //Stream<String> wordsStream = Arrays.asList(words).stream();
    for( int i=0; i < controlWords.length; i++ )
    {
        if( !Arrays.asList(words).stream().anyMatch( Predicate.isEqual(controlWords[i]) ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как верно отметил @kofemann, `Stream` — одноразовая штука. В этом плане он похож на `Iterator`. Чтобы использовать его несколько раз, нужно создавать новый `Stream`. Если вы по какой-то причине хотите создание `Stream` вынести наружу (например, чтобы вам `Stream` передавали параметром), но при этом вам он нужен несколько раз, рекомендуется использовать `Supplier<Stream>`:

```
private boolean test(String line) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    Supplier<Stream<String>> wordsStream = () -> Arrays.asList(words).stream();
    for (int i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
        if (!wordsStream.get().anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(controlWords[i]))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ещё обратите внимание, что есть метод `Arrays.stream()`, поэтому вам необязательно заворачивать сперва слова в список:

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> wordsStream = () -> Arrays.stream(words);
```

Наконец, заметьте, что ваша задача решается гораздо легче старыми способами без Stream API:

```
private boolean test(String line) {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
    for (int i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
        if (!words.contains(controlWords[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Однако можно повернуть в другую сторону и уже сам цикл `for` свернуть в `Stream` из `controlWords`:

```
private boolean test(String line) {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
    return Arrays.stream(controlWords).allMatch(controlWord -> words.contains(controlWord));
}
```

Тут можно заменить лямбду на ссылку:

```
private boolean test(String line) {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
    return Arrays.stream(controlWords).allMatch(words::contains);
}
```

И даже заинлайнить `words` (после инлайнинга он всё равно один раз вычисляется!)

```
private boolean test(String line) {
    return Arrays.stream(controlWords).allMatch(Arrays.asList(line.split(" "))::contains);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!!!

Answer (score 2):

Stream нельзя использовать несколько раз. Поток пропускается один раз. По этому, если цикл повторяется больше одного раза то код работает не корректно.

Во втором примере, каждый раз создаётся новый stream .

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительный код, который позволяет удобно использовать Stream

```java
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.function.Consumer;
    import java.util.function.Function;
    import java.util.function.Predicate;
    import java.util.function.Supplier;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class HStream<T> {

        @SafeVarargs
        public HStream(T... values) { this.value = () -> Stream.of(values); }

        private Supplier<Stream<T>> value;

        public HStream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> action) {
            Supplier<Stream<T>> current = get();
            this.value = () -> current.get().filter(action);
            return this;
        }

        public boolean allMatch(Predicate<? super T> action) { return this.value.get().allMatch(action); }
        public boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> action) { return this.value.get().anyMatch(action); }
        public boolean noneMatch(Predicate<? super T> action) { return this.value.get().noneMatch(action); }

        public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) { this.value.get().forEach(action); }

        public Optional<T> findFirst() { return this.value.get().findFirst(); }
        public Optional<T> findAny() { return this.value.get().findAny(); }
    }
```

**Скорость падала в 4 раза**

Если вы все равно хотите это использовать подобным образом, можете взять за основу часть моего проекта [HStream](https://github.com/HZERR/HStream)